# Am I legally allowed to build my own rocket and fly to space by myself?

Tags: travel, aviation, space

Let's say I have all the technology, knowledge, materials, money and time to build my own homemade space rocket. Am I allowed to fly to space with it?

Comment: What is your jurisdiction?

Comment: [The Astronaut Farmer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0469263/) Obviously fiction, but *very* related :)

Comment: Would anyone, who is _so_ capable, ask a permission to do so? What if you don't get one? What if you fly regardless? Will they pursue you to sue you?

Comment: @PF4Public Violation of airspace can result in your airplane being shot down

Comment: @Trish We are not talking about a mere airplane, we are talking about a rocket! Shooting a rocket _in Space_ with another rocket is a challenging task. But anyway, do you have any reference/document for that? I'm asking, because otherwise one could simply state that _any_ flying object could be shot down, without even violating anything.

Comment: @PF4Public any flying vehicle in the US Airspace has to adhere to FAA rules. And flying into restricted airspace (**including space**) or breaking contact with ground control leads to interceptors being sent [after your vehicle](https://www.airspacemag.com/flight-today/dont-cross-that-line-5841988/). A rocket however might be much easier be misidentified as the launch of an ICBM - which might prompt just about ANY state to shoot it down.

Comment: The linked article even mentions using ground-based systems to guard the US airspace, which is the only way to shoot down a rocket. And *"“The authority to shoot down a civilian aircraft is delegated to a very small number of very senior officials, civilian and military, within the Department of Defense,” McHale said."* And violating airspace is a **felony** - yes, they will *also* go after you or your company in addition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might depend on where you are. I think it's illegal in North Korea. In the US, it is legally encouraged, by the [Commercial Space Launch Act of 1984](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_Space_Launch_Act_of_1984), especially the part that says "Congress declares that the general welfare of the United States requires that the Administration seek and encourage, to the maximum extent possible, the fullest commercial use of space". Previously, Congress passed the [Communications Satellite Act of 1962](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_Satellite_Act_of_1962), which first expressed an interest in allowing commercial flights, but there was substantial opposition to non-government entities in space. There are a number of legal private space adventures from numerous countries.

As Nate Eldridge points out, you still need government (FAA) permission. So it's legal to blast yourself into space in the same sense that it's legal to drive or to open a business.

Comment: It might be *generally* encouraged in the US, but that doesn't mean it's legal to just do it.  You need a permit from the FAA.  See https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ast/licenses_permits/

Comment: True: I didn't interpret the question as asking "Can I just go fly to the moon?"

Comment: @NateEldredge technically, you need the FAA allowance for *any* flight in *US Airspace*. But if you'd launch in... let's say Point Nemo (the spot most remote from all coasts), you'd be out of any airspace jurisdiction.